# C programming printf not printing when used nested loop

Tags: c

I'm learning about multidimensional array in C programming. But the **printf** function is not working. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  int array[2][3][4]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
     {
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            array[i][j][k] = k;
            printf("array[%d][%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, k, array[i][j][k]);
        };
    };

};
printf("Loop is finished!");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're overrunning your array indices. `int[2]` means you have 2 elements, i.e. you can access indices 0 and 1, but you're accessing 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to loop out of bounds.

Take the first dimension, 2, your loop is < 3....  so its going to use indexes `0` `1` `2`.  only `0` and `1` are valid.  change your loops to `i < 2`, `j < 3` and `k < 4` respectively.

Comment: There are only two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off by one errors.

Comment: Thank you solved my problem :) but why I can't use 3 elements for [2], for example {1,2,3} because of null terminator?

Comment: does it works properly? it having lots of syntax errors see my answer

Comment: @Amession you only allocated space for 2 things, if you want 3 things, make the size 3.

Comment: it is because the array is declared as ` int array[2][3][4];` you can make the change as said in this answer or correct the errors and see my answer which will also give result change is that` int array[3][4][5];`

Comment: Showing support is a good thing so i up voted the answer since it is correct

Answer (score 0):

This program will not give result since it having lots of `Syntax errors`. you need not to be give `;`- semicolon after `for` loop

syntax for `For Loop` is:

```
FOR( initialization expression;condition expression;update expression)
{
\\Loop content comes here
}
```

And also `C` will not permit `Instant Declaration`, variables should be declare @ the declaration section.

Your Program can be improved by applying these changes, then it gives output. the code snippet will be like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  int array[3][4][5]; 
  int i,j,k;
  for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
     for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++)
      {
        for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            array[i][j][k] = k;
            printf("array[%d][%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, k, array[i][j][k]);
        }
      }
  }
  printf("Loop is finished!");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes the semicolon after bracket was wrong :) but your program doesn't work, the last printf won't show the output